# Почему не работает слайдер swipe вместе с jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, slider, swipe

Есть конкретный слайдер Swipe. Он может работать и с jquery, и без. Проблема в том, что не скроллится мышкой и не работают клавиши в нём, если есть jquery. Без jquery — всё отлично работает. Подключал версию и с jquery, и без — при наличии последнего скролл перестаёт работать, консоль при скролле (версия без jq, но jq подключен) выдаёт вот это:

```
scripts.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
at t.b.getTranslate (scripts.min.js:2)
at t.b.getWrapperTranslate (scripts.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.b.onTouchMove (scripts.min.js:2)
```

Инициализация в скриптах:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    mousewheelControl: true,
    keyboardControl: true,
    scrollbarHide: true
})
```

Как побороть эту ошибку?
Версии либов самые свежие

Answer (score 1):

Всё решилось просто. В версии без jq после инициализации слайдера с параметрами, пишем

```
mySwiper.enableKeyboardControl();
mySwiper.enableMousewheelControl();
```

А не в параметрах.